How to authenticate with Firebase CLI now that firebase login --token <token> is deprecated?
I've been using the Firebase CLI tools for a while, and I've always authenticated by generating a token with firebase login:ci and then logging in with firebase login --token <token>.
However, I recently discovered that firebase login --token <token> is now deprecated.
What is the current recommended method for logging in to the Firebase CLI? Are there new commands or processes I need to follow to authenticate?
I need this specifically for use in GitLab pipelines. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/17sv8x7/since_loginci_is_getting_deprecated_how_can_i/ ?

See the documentation for Use the CLI with CI systems:

The Firebase CLI requires a browser to complete authentication, but
the CLI is fully compatible with CI and other headless environments.

On a machine with a browser, install the Firebase CLI.

Start the signin process by running the following command:


firebase login:ci

Visit the URL provided, then log in using a Google account.

Print a new refresh token. The current CLI session will not be
affected.

Store the output token in a secure but accessible way in your CI
system.

Use this token when running firebase commands. You can use either of
the following two options:

Option 1: Store the token as the environment variable FIREBASE_TOKEN. Your system will automatically use the token.




Basically, you're being told to use the FIREBASE_TOKEN environment variable instead of --token.

I don't understand why the official docs recommend login with personal accountsto obtain a token for a build/release pipeline a whole dev team will use? Why aren't better auth methods promoted in the docs, surely a personal access token is not best practice? The env variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS also seems to be not recommended, but at least it's super easy to set up, it is not tied to one user, and modern CI systems like Azure DevOps offer secure storage for such files.

I had this issue too! Use firebase login --no-localhost. Follow the instructions, and it'll spit out a token. Then, paste your authentication token into the terminal.

I don't see how this helps as an alternative to login with an token or to automate deployment.

Sorry. I misunderstood the question.
